# Find two vectors that are parallel to w and have magnitude three times the magnitude of w

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm just trying to figure out how to begin to solve this question!

Given w= (0, 1, 3), find two vectors that are parallel to w and have magnitude three times the magnitude of w.

Any help or references to videos that could help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you know about vectors, terms like 'parallel' and 'magnitude', how vectors are written as lists of numbers, etc.?

Comment: There seem to be two different definitions of "parallel" so you really should look up how **your** textbook or instructor defined "parallel vectors." (The wording of the question strongly suggests what their definition is, however.)

Comment: I understand the definitions and how to write out lists of numbers, I'm just not too sure how to find a vector that is parallel.

Comment: So, ask yourself, is $(1,2,3)$ parallel to $(0,1,3)$? Why/why not? If you can answer that, you should be able to figure out what a vector has to do to be parallel to $(0,1,3)$.

Comment: That helped so much, thank you all!!